# Referencing instance as 'this' in prototype object assignment

Tags: javascript

The example below contains some formatting functions and an object which maps between fields and formatting functions.

```
MyObject = function() {};
MyObject.prototype.formatters = {
    'money': function(value) { return "&euro;" + value },
    'hyperlink': function(value) { return "<a href='"+value+"'>"+value+"</a>";
}
MyObject.prototype.fieldFormatters = {
    'field1': this.formatters.money,
    'field2': this.formatters.hyperlink
}
```

Unfortunately, the context in `fieldFormatters` is `window` at the time of evaluation, so I can not reference `this.formatters`. Is there an alternative way to reference `this.formatters` or a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only functions are executed in context.

```
MyObject = function() {};
MyObject.prototype.formatters = {
    'money': function(value) { return "&euro;" + value },
    'hyperlink': function(value) { return "<a href='"+value+"'>"+value+"</a>";
}
MyObject.prototype.getFieldFormatters = function () {
    // here this is instance of MyObject having correct __proto__
    return {
        'field1': this.formatters.money,
        'field2': this.formatters.hyperlink
    }
}
```

But you can do a trick: use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters):

```
Object.defineProperty(MyObject.prototype, "fieldFormatters", {get : function () {
    // here this is instance of MyObject having correct __proto__
    return {
        'field1': this.formatters.money,
        'field2': this.formatters.hyperlink
    }
}})
```

Comment: Good ideas, but `__defineGetter__` lacks cross-browser support. I came up with an alternative by calling the function with context: `MyObject.prototype.fieldFormatters = (function () { return ... }).call(MyObject.prototype);`. But in the end it's down to personal preference.

Comment: @bcoughlan, there is a ECMAScript Edition 5 [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). You can use it to define getters (I've updated my code snippet).

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer back to the `prototype`, not an instance:

```
MyObject.prototype.fieldFormatters = {
    'field1': MyObject.prototype.formatters.money,
    'field2': MyObject.prototype.formatters.hyperlink
};
```